# How do I remove duplicate #include directives?

Tags: perl, hash

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <VideoInChain.h>
#include <VideoOutChain.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
...//rest of code
```

There are system header files duplication which I need to remove without affecting rest of the code

I tried

```
sub uniq {
  my %seen = ();
  my @r = ();
  foreach my $a (@_) {
     unless ($seen{$a}) {           
         push @r, $a;
         $seen{$a} = 1;
      }
    }
  return @r;
  }
  @lines_temp = uniq(@lines_temp);
```

but it removes all type of duplication including '(', '{' and blank spaces

I need to remove only duplicate system files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sub uniq {
  my %seen;
  my @r;
  for my $a (@_) {
     my ($m) = $a =~ /#include\s+<(.+?)>/;
     push @r, $a if !$m or !$seen{$m}++;
  }
  return @r;
}
@lines_temp = uniq(@lines_temp);
```

or

```
sub uniq {
  my %seen;
  return grep {
     my ($m) =~ /#include\s+<(.+?)>/;
     !$m or !$seen{$m}++;
  } @_;
}
@lines_temp = uniq(@lines_temp);
```

or oneliner,

```
perl -ne '($m) = /#include\s+<(.+?)>/; print if !$m or !$s{$m}++' file
```

Comment: its a big script and i am new to perl.i need help to make it run within the script and not run it from cmd

Comment: thanks .it works fine now. But can u plz give link to some material or explain in short, what does it means \s+<(.+?)>/

Comment: @user2628315  `(.+?)` captures string inside `<>`. Check http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html